# Programmatically check if a field in a domino document is a Text or a TextList - is it possible?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, document, lotus-domino

I am trying to implement a method that replaces all values inside a Hashmap with all the values inside a document.

The idea behind that is that I loop through all `items` that I get from `Document.getItems()` and simply use the `Item.getType()` method so I can decide what type I use for which field.

Something like that:

```java
private void replace(SomeClass model, Document document) {
    Map<String, Object> objectsMap = model.getObjectsMap();

    Vector<Item> items = document.getItems();

    for(Item item : items) {
        if(item.getType() == Item.TEXT) {
            model.add(item.getName(), item.getValueString()); // model.add(...) is basically a Map.put(String key, Object value);
        } else if(item.getType() == Item.AUTHORS) {
            // ...
        } else if(/*...*/) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I cannot distinguish between a `Text` and a `TextList` because `getType()` returns 1280 for both.

Has anyone tried something like that already or maybe can give me a hint of what approach might be a workaround?

**EDIT**

Regarding the idea from one of the comments, to use a `TextList` when `item.getValues().size() > 1` and `Text` otherwise:
As mentioned in the comment the problem is, that I want to be able to use the field later as well.

For example:
If I have a `TextList` field with one item in the document, and I would use the approach described above, I would put a String inside the `Map` for this field.
If I want to add more Items to this field (which should be a `Vector` since originally it was a `TextList`) I wouldn't be able to - at least not in a straight forward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotesItems always return A Vector for values. There is no distinction between text and textList. However what you could do: get the form object and check the field properties. If allow multi value is ticked, then you can presume it was intended as textList rather than text. 
That should sort your conversion decision. You also could flag items with more than one value that don’t have allow multi value set in the field - code would have done that

Comment: Well that is unfortunate, that there is no way to reliably check if it is a Text or a TextList - However your answer is the best one so far. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to recheck your mental model. The value of a NotesItem is neither a text nor a textlist. It is a vector. Now you want to map that vector to a text list (easy) or for the special case that it has one value only AND the INTENTION of the developer was that it should be limited to one value only. This intention is programmatically documented in the field on the form. That’s quite reliable

Comment: The only catch: since it is an “intention” and not an enforceable constraint, code, but not the UI, can add additional values to an item that was intended as single value. Normal mortal users hardly get access to such code and you could read the form also on Notes -> Java conversion and treat unintended multivalues as single string using item.text

Answer (score 0):

You could check the size of item.getValues() - which returns a Vector . If the size of the vector is > 0 it is a textilst.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Because if I get a `Text` field using `item.getValues` and ask for the size it will be 1. And if it is a `TextList` field with one item, `size()` will return 1 as well

Comment: @VIC So there is your solution, if the size is 1 it's a Text and if it's larger it's a TexList. If it's smaller or null then it's empty

Comment: @JoakimDanielson not really. If I want to add more items to the `TextList` (which should be a `Vector` at this point)  that had only one item so far, I can't do this anymore since we converted the `Vector` to a `TextList` and it will be considered a `String` inside the `Map` - I think I forgot to mention that the replace functionality should be able to handle both: document to map, and map to document

Comment: Unfortunately, `TextList` is not a type. You can set 'Allow Multiple values' on a form field, but there is no direct way to get to this property.
If the field is on a form (which is not always the case), you might try to retrieve the property trough DXL, but this is very complex and time consuming.
In Java, all fields are considered MV. Even computeWithForm won't correct this. It is only when you save the document through the UI (Notes Client), that it takes Single/Multi value into account.